# Can I break my lease because of being lied to

Tags: united-states, illinois

So my lease stated we are paying water and sewer per usage in the lease, but when it came time to be billed for water and sewer after living here for a week, the bill was/is $300. When I confronted them, they said the water and sewer is currently charged per resident and not per usage because the water meters are broken. They have known for years that they were broken and didn't disclose this to us at least signing, and our lease states "per usage" charge for water and sewer. Is this legal? I feel like they are defrauding us for extra money that they aren't owed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No, you cannot break your lease

Your contract contains a [misrepresentation](https://www.lawhandbook.sa.gov.au/ch10s03s06.php). A misrepresentation may be a cause for terminating a contract if it was [material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materiality_(law)); that is, you would need to prove that if you had known that water and sewage were charged per resident instead of by usage, you would not have entered the lease. This will be very difficult to prove.

### Require them to follow the lease

Your lease says you will be charged per usage. Pay them the usage shown on their (broken) meter. Until they fix it, that will be nothing.